# draw datatable is null when i use where in my query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I have some problem with showing data in datatable, the problem is when I using the query clause like `where` condition, the `draw` in datatable is had a null value but when I'm not using the `where` condition, the data will be display on my datatable, is anything wrong with my query in codeigniter?

model :

```
var $attendance = 'attendance';
var $employee = 'employee';
var $project = 'project';

var $column = [
    null, 'attendance.no_reg', 'employee.name', 'project.project_name', 'project.project_code'
];

var $column_search = [
   'attendance.no_reg', 'employee.name', 'project.project_name', 'project.project_code'
];

var $column_order = [
   null, 'attendance.no_reg', 'employee.name', 'project.project_name', 'project.project_code'
];

private function _showDaily() {
     $selectedValues = $this->input->post('selectedValues');
     $this->db->select($this->column);
     $this->db->from($this->attendance);
     // $this->db->where("project_code", $selectedValues);
     $this->db->join($this->employee, "attendance.no_reg = employee.no_reg");
     $this->db->join($this->project, "attendance.project_id = project.id");
     $this->db->group_by("attendance.no_reg"); 

     // length table
     $i = 0;

     foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // initial looping for grouping insert a text search
     {
          error_reporting(0);
          if ($_POST['search']['value']) { // if the datatable make a input search with POST method
          if ($i === 0) { // initial first condition for first column
               $this->db->group_start();
               $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
          } else {
               $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
          }
          if (count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) // condition if the text search value counting same with $i value then minus 1
               $this->db->group_end();
          }
          $i++;
      }

      if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
          $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
      }

}
public function showsDaily()
{
    $this->_showDaily();
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result();
}
```

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: You're saying that the data is not showing when you use `where` but nowhere in your code have you mentioned `where clause`.

Comment: oh sorry I'm forget to changing the query, thanks for reminder me

Comment: is `$selectedValues` an array?

Comment: no, `$selectedValues` is a value from a parameter in Controller I have made before, It means `$selectedValues` is value from my input text

Comment: Try putting `where` after `join` also specify the table name in `where` -   `$this->db->where("your_table_name.project_code", $selectedValues);`

Comment: I already try using that query but didn't work